# Where are the authorize attributes coming from on the identity pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

A scaffolded ASP.NET Core Identity UI comes without authorization attributes. For example, `LogOut.cshtml` and `LogOut.cshtml.cs` have no authorization attribute. Yet, an unauthenticated user is redirected to the login page if visiting it, and indeed investigating the endpoint data for `Identity/Account/LogOut` indicates the presence of an `AuthorizeAttribute` (I used [this neat way of displaying the endpoint data](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/endpoint-debugging-in-asp-dot-net-core-3-applications)).

This is weird for a number of reasons. First, the `LogOut.chtml` contains logic for the unauthenticated case. On the sources, the original model in `LogOut.chtml.cs` even has an `AllowAnonymous` attribute.

Besides this particular weirdness with `LogOut`, I'm more genreally trying to understand what determines those attributes/configurations here if it's not the scaffolded pages I have in my code - and none of them came with any authorization attributes.

I have everything straight from the wizard, there's also nothing done to the `AppBuilder` except `MapRazorPages` that should do something identity-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity.UI configures the global `Authorize` property for `Logout` and `Manage` by default, but not configured for other pages. So you need to add the `AllowAnonymous` attribute to directly access the Logout Page without logging in.

You can see this in the [source code of IdentityDefaultUIConfigureOptions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3fcd84946cf63794a3913a79d47f5143ea0f30ae/src/Identity/UI/src/IdentityDefaultUIConfigureOptions.cs#L33). The `AddDefaultIdentity` you used when adding Identity contains `DefaultUI`, so it will add constraints to specific pages by default.

Also, if you don't want to use the `AllowAnonymous` attribute, you can also use the global configuration in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(option =>
{
    option.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
});
```

Reference link: [Razor Pages authorization conventions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Great, thanks! That's answers all my questions.